# backslashes "\" added in JSON string for web service in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services

In my project I need to send JSON object in web service API call. I have converted JSON from array.

```
do {

       let theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
                        param ,
                        options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

       var theJSONText : String = String(data: theJSONData,
                        encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

       print(theJSONText)

       theJSONText = theJSONText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

       print(theJSONText)

       let newParam = ["ESignData":theJSONText]


} catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
```

it print string correctly as

```
{"EntNum":"47","JobNo":"1737753","ClientID":"100","HospNo":"1","QAReason":"","DoctorNo":"1694","Action":"Sign"}
{"EntNum":"47","JobNo":"1737753","ClientID":"100","HospNo":"1","QAReason":"","DoctorNo":"1694","Action":"Sign"}
```

Now When I try to send this `newParam` dictionary in API call, it contains "\" in string parameters of JSON string.

```
WebService.PostURL(mainLink, methodname: ESIGNTHISDOC, param: newParam, userName: AUTH_USERNAME, password: AUTH_PWD, CompletionHandler: { (success, response) in
})
```

And in that web service method I have print param.

```
Param =  {
    ESignData = "{\"EntNum\":\"47\",\"JobNo\":\"1737753\",\"ClientID\":\"100\",\"HospNo\":\"1\",\"QAReason\":\"\",\"DoctorNo\":\"1694\",\"Action\":\"Sign\"}";
}
```

Now in this I know it is obvious in iOS because of " in string. Now the problem is that there are lots of APIs working in android app, and the API developer doesn't want to update his code according to us.

I know this problem happens because of adding JSON string in dictionary as parameter. But I have not proper justification for that so if any proof will be also helpful for me to convince him.

Any solution to convert the JSON string without backslash in iOS? I need to fix from my side if possible. Any help will be appreciate.

EDIT :

On server side it needs like

```
ESignData = {"EntNum":"47","JobNo":"1737753","ClientID":"100","HospNo":"1","QAReason":"","DoctorNo":"1694","Action":"Sign"}
```

If I pass this as parameter in POSTMAN than it gives success message. But not with our object with "\" in it.

EDIT 2:

Now printing the `newParam` dictionary:

```
print(newParam)
print("-------------------------")
print(newParam["ESignData"])
```

And logs :

```
["ESignData": "{\"EntNum\":\"47\",\"JobNo\":\"1737754\",\"ClientID\":\"100\",\"HospNo\":\"1\",\"QAReason\":\"\",\"DoctorNo\":\"1694\",\"Action\":\"Sign\"}"]
-------------------------
Optional("{\"EntNum\":\"47\",\"JobNo\":\"1737754\",\"ClientID\":\"100\",\"HospNo\":\"1\",\"QAReason\":\"\",\"DoctorNo\":\"1694\",\"Action\":\"Sign\"}")
```

And by debug :

```
Printing description of newParam:
▿ 1 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "ESignData"
    - .1 : "{\"EntNum\":\"47\",\"JobNo\":\"1737754\",\"ClientID\":\"100\",\"HospNo\":\"1\",\"QAReason\":\"\",\"DoctorNo\":\"1694\",\"Action\":\"Sign\"}"
```

So it shows that it is in our dictionary. All the " are joined by \.

Comment: I don't know how you printed the param on the server side, but seeing the enclosing `"`s, seemingly-two-character-sequence `\"` would be representing a single character `"`. Many debugging outputs use this sort of "String-literal-like" notation. I believe your parameters have been sent to the server successfully.

Comment: @OOPer This is printed on our side not on server side, We just got fail response because they can't fetch required parameters.

Comment: Then, the reason is not the backslash.  Check the API reference if your `newParam` is valid for the API.

Comment: let me edit the question.

Comment: The code you have shown in `Params =` part of your post is formatted in NSDictionary's plist-like format. Those \ s are not sent to the server.

Comment: @OOPer, then there is something mistake in our service call? because it can't decode on server side properly. If I print description of 'newParam' while debug then it also print \.

Comment: What do you see with `print(newParam["ESignData"]!)`?

Comment: I need to repeat for EDIT 2, it's the debugging format: String-literal like notation. The actual content does not contain backslash. Do you think if you write `let str = "\""`, `str` is a two-character string? And how debugger will show you the content of `str`? (And add `!` to the end of `newParam["ESignData"]`.)

Comment: I understand you and that notation. But why this becomes problem on server side to decode that JSON string? It should be acceptable JSON, Right?

Comment: My guess is you have mistaken the usage of the API. Any of the API references say you need to generate JSON string yourself? If your API function `WebService.PostURL` can generate JSON internally, the data would be double encoded.

Comment: @OOPer Yes they give a document of API in which it clearly mention to send JSON object. And if we can't convert to JSON and send direct 'param'  replacing the 'theJSONText' then also it doesn't give a success response. It means it is also not valid on server side.

Comment: Then I cannot say anything without more info. Waiting for updates.

Comment: @Max how you find the solutions of this problem , i am also facing the same issue .

Comment: @nivritgupta It will be managed from server side, we can't from iOS side. In My server they use PHP function `stripslashes()` to get proper json string.

Comment: @Max at our side why we can able to handle this , any idea

Comment: @nivritgupta Yes we can't because we convert object into string and strings contains `"` at start and end of string, so it makes `\"` to denote main string contains substrings.

Comment: @max Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue today. For me it appears that the default encoding for any `NSURLRequest` is a string. So, somewhere between my creating the dictionary request and the server parsing it, the backslashes would appear and the server had problems with my payload.

I solved the issue by explicitly stating that my payload was JSON by setting the content type header.

```
    [authRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Now when I create JSON data from a dictionary, the backslashes don't appear and the server is able to parse everything correctly.

Code snippet below for completeness:

```
   NSMutableURLRequest *authRequest = [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:authURL] mutableCopy];
[authRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[authRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *bodyDictionary = @{@"User_Name": user, @"Password_Hash": password};

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:bodyDictionary]) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:bodyDictionary options:0 error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        [authRequest setHTTPBody:bodyData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to convert to JSON DATA %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```